# get objects from SQL query hibernate Java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

so I am Trying to get a table from MySQL via hibernate and store it as a List so I can get variables from it. i know that the .getResultsList() stores an untyped list but its giving me a warning and error with the following code

```
public List<ToDoList> list (Session s)
    {
        return s.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM todolist").getResultList();

    }
```

```
The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<ToDoList>
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to toDo.ToDoList
    at toDo.ToDoMain.main(ToDoMain.java:46)
```

how can I properly get the list of objects from MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate 5.2+ I would recommend to get the EntityManager from your Hibernate session and use the EntityManager to create the query.
There you can add the type of the of the expected result.

```
public List<ToDoList> list (Session s){
  EntityManager em = s.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
  Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM todolist", ToDoList.class);

  return q.getResultList();
}
```